# I try to show variable from the controller to blade in laravel but the result is "Undefined Variable"

Tags: laravel

I try to show variable from the controller to blade in laravel but the result is "Undefined Variable $bedrijven , i tried to not use as bedrijf but with no avail

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daXub.png)"

The controller

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Bedrijf;

class Bedrijven extends Controller
{
    //
    function viewLoad()
    {
 return Bedrijf::all();      
 return view ('list',['Bedrijven'=>$data]);
    }
    
}
//
{
    //
    function account (Request $req)
    {
        return $req->input();
    }
}
```

The blade file

```
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>bedrijven_id</td>
   <td>Body</td>
  </tr>
@foreach($bedrijven as $bedrijf)
<tr>
    <td>{{$bedrijf['id']}}</td>
    <td>{{$bedrijf['bedrijven_id']}}</td>
    <td>{{$bedrijf['body']}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
</body>
</html>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the route

```
Route::get('list', [Bedrijven::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: `return` stops further execution. From [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php): "If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call." Feel free to learn basics well, first.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller there is not a `$data` variable that's why it shows a error

to fix it try this:

```
function viewLoad()
{
  $data = Bedrijf::all();      
  return view ('list',['Bedrijven'=>$data]);
}
```

instead of :

```
function viewLoad()
{
  return Bedrijf::all();      
  return view ('list',['Bedrijven'=>$data]);
}
```

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Minor spelling mistake and the methods controller does not match the route definition. It is quite easy to use compact, to create the array for the view data.

```
public function show() {
    $bedrijven = Bedrijf::all(); 

    return view ('list', compact('bedrijven'));
}
```

Now the blade code will match the compacted data.

```
@foreach($bedrijven as $bedrijf)
```

Comment: still the same error

Comment: this should work, if before the foreach you @dd($bedrijven) what does that say?

Comment: i posted this in the wrong blade file apperantly i will now do it on the correct blade file